# Use existing subnet group for RDS

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

I try to create RDS on already existing subnet.
There are three subnet.

```
subnet-0b5985476dee1f20c public on 1d
subnet-085c85398f27adbfd isolated on 1c
subnet-0fdd37150bfff91f0 isolated on 1d
```

So, I want to use second and third subnet as subnet group/

My code is here below.

```
const VPCID='vpc-0867d6797e6XXXXXb';
const vpc = ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this, "VPC", {
  vpcId:VPCID
});

const mySecurityGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, 'sg-allfordevelop', {
  vpc,
  description: 'Allow sql access to database',
  allowAllOutbound: true,   
  securityGroupName: `cdk-st-${targetEnv}-sg`
}); 
mySecurityGroup.addIngressRule(ec2.Peer.anyIpv4(), ec2.Port.tcp(3306),'allow mysql port');

const dbInstance = new rds.DatabaseInstance(this, 'Instance', {
  engine: rds.DatabaseInstanceEngine.mysql({
    version: rds.MysqlEngineVersion.VER_8_0_19,
  }),
  vpc,
  securityGroups:[mySecurityGroup],
  instanceIdentifier:`cdk-${targetEnv}-rds`,
  vpcSubnets: {
    subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED,
  },
  instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.BURSTABLE2, ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO),
  removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
  databaseName:`st${targetEnv}`,
  credentials: rds.Credentials.fromPassword('django',new cdk.SecretValue("mypass"))
});
```

However it makes template here below.

There are not existed ids here.

Does it mean trying to make new subnet ?

How can I indicate to use already existed subnets?

```
"InstanceSubnetGroupF2CBA54F": {
  "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup",
  "Properties": {
    "DBSubnetGroupDescription": "Subnet group for Instance database",
    "SubnetIds": [
      "subnet-0b5985476dee1f20c",
      "subnet-0d7c1590c61b62782"
    ]
  },
  "Metadata": {
    "aws:cdk:path": "st-dev-base-stack/Instance/SubnetGroup/Default"
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

There are old information cached in cdk.context.json.

I delete this file, it works.